# laravel return Unexpected token error when i use vuex

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am working with laravel and vuejs. when I try to access from method from my store I get unexpected token error with the vuex mapAction.

This is the code in my vue component: the error is originating from the three dot (...) in front of the mapActions.

```
import { mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
    name:'SettingComponent',
    methods(){
       ...mapActions(['fetchSetting'])
    },
    created(){
       this.fetchSetting();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try formatting it this way

```
methods:{
   ...mapActions(['fetchSetting'])
},
```

Comment: @evans it compiled in vscode but i get this error " Error in created hook: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatch' of undefined""

Comment: can you show the code where you use dispatch. also did you register vuex correctly globally?

Comment: thanks @evans i appreciate the help, i did not add 'store' in my new Vue instance